# SQL query for adjacent model in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been struggling to come up with a SQL query for one of my tables in Postgres 9.4. The table is a typical adjacent model:

```
Table: categories

id | code | parent_id 
----+------+-----------
  1 | la   |          
  2 | wst  |         1
  3 | sfv  |         1
  4 | lac  |         1
  5 | sgv  |         1
  6 | lgb  |         1
  7 | ant  |         1
  8 | sf   |          
  9 | sfc  |         8
 10 | sby  |         8
 11 | eby  |         8
 12 | pen  |         8
 13 | nby  |         8
 14 | scz  |         8
```

I need a query that will return either:

a) a list of children ids for the top category (e.g. `la`, `sf`) or 
b) its own id if the searched category is already the child category (e.g `wst`, `sfv` etc.).

In other words:

```
select id ... where categories.id=1 // => 2,3,4,5,6,7
select id ... where categories.id=2 // => 2
select id ... where categories.id=3 // => 3
... ... ...
select id ... where categories.id=8 // => 9,10,11,12,13,14
select id ... where categories.id=9 // => 9
select id ... where categories.id=10 // => 10
... ... ...
```

I've been getting close, but can't nail it down. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `Id` to both `Id` and `Parent_Id` column. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   category
WHERE  ( id = 1 
          OR parent_id = 1 )
       AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

Considering that `Parent_Id` is a `integer` column and when a `Id` is **parent** then `parent_id` column will be `NULL`

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4de1f/2)**

Comment: Ah-ah-ah. Why I couldn't think of that? Simply genius. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "id",max(case when "parent_id" ='1' then "code" end),"parent_id" 
FROM "categories" group by "id","parent_id"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at it. I've tried running this query, but it didn't return the results I was expecting.